# Leaflet Map Search gets no Results and Error: this._retrieveData is not a function

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using Leaflet Map and want to add the Search Box Tool from Leaflet. The following code shows how i build my markers with content in popup:

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var name = data[i][0];
        var space = " loc.";
        var lat = data[i][1];
        var lon = data[i][2];
        if (data[i][4] == 1) {
            var Icon = new L.Icon({
                iconUrl: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-gold.png",
                shadowUrl: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png",
                iconSize: [25, 41],
                iconAnchor: [12, 41],
                popupAnchor: [1, -34],
                shadowSize: [41, 41]
            });
        }
        else if (data[i][4] == 2) {
            var Icon = new L.Icon({
                iconUrl: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-grey.png",
                shadowUrl: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png",
                iconSize: [25, 41],
                iconAnchor: [12, 41],
                popupAnchor: [1, -34],
                shadowSize: [41, 41]
            });
        }
        else {
            var Icon = new L.Icon({
                iconUrl: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-orange.png",
                shadowUrl: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png",
                iconSize: [25, 41],
                iconAnchor: [12, 41],
                popupAnchor: [1, -34],
                shadowSize: [41, 41]
            });
        }
        var popup = name.bold() + space;
        var marker = L.marker([lat, lon], { icon: Icon }).addTo(map);
        marker.bindPopup(popup);

    }
```

After that i added the Searchbox:

```
map.addControl(new L.Control.Search({ layer: popup }));
```

It finds no results and outputs the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._retrieveData is not a function
_fillRecordsCache leaflet-search.js:735
timerKeypress leaflet-search.js:691
setTimeout handler*_handleKeypress leaflet-search.js:690
o DomEvent.js:108
```

Am I missing something here? Do I call the wrong layer, or is it not possible to search in the popup content itself?

Answer (score 0):

The option `layer` needs to be set to an `L.LayerGroup` object. See [leaflet-search GitHub README](https://github.com/stefanocudini/leaflet-search) and e.g the source code of [the simple example](https://opengeo.tech/maps/leaflet-search/examples/simple.html).